# Is it possible to create a "double-decker" toolbar in the Windows taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, icons, user-interface, usability

For toolbars within the Windows taskbar, Win7 lets you specify if you want to use small or large icons.  If you select small icons for a toolbar, but large icons for the primary taskbar, the icons in the toolbar occupy half the height of the taskbar.

Another row of icons will fit nicely directly under those small toolbar icons.  Is there a way to get a taskbar ***toolbar*** to have two rows ("double-decker") of small icons in Windows 7 without making the entire taskbar double-height?

Comment: This super cool feature was retired in Windows XP (ARRAGGH!)  It *might* have existed in Vista but I don't remember because I hated Vista.  It was one of my favorite features.  You also used to be able to dock as many toolbars you wanted to any part of the screen or even leave them floating.  Dragging ANY folder to the edge of the screen turned it into a toolbar before they killed this feature.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Ah! I thought I remembered being able to do this!  Do you know of any software that allows this?  If so, I can ask a related question on Software Recommendations SE.

Comment: Sorry sir, I gave up after they killed it and go used to a different workflow.  Your name/handle is awesome.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thanks for the compliment.  Your name as well.  :)  If you think of anything, just holler.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy to do.

Unlock the taskbar, and grab the upper edge with the mouse and make it larger.

I just did this again here and it works fine.

Lock the taskbar after.

> Is there a way to get a taskbar toolbar to have two rows?

As I understand your question, no. A toolbar can only have a shortcut (up arrow) in the toolbar. Again as I understand your question, Windows 7 (looking here) is the same way.

If you wish to add a Toolbar, right click on the Taskbar and add it. It will show up as a double up arrow.

I added a screen shot of the new Toolbar I use and the Flyout.

If you wish to have this particular toolbar:

> Right Click on the Taskbar Select Toolbar, New Toolbar. Add the
> following content in the space provided:
> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs . Save the toolbar.
> It should call itself Programs.

You can make the toolbar show up in the taskbar by dragging one of the separators over top of the icon. This, for me, leaves a taskbar with some icons and still a flyout. I tend to need more predictability in my setup but that, of course, is personal preference. All you need is here.

[image: Example Toolbar]

Comment: Thanks John.  But that makes the entire taskbar twice as high.  I want the taskbar to remain at its default height (the height of 1 large icon), but have a toolbar within the taskbar have two rows of small icons.

Comment: The taskbar is a uniform height across the screen: Small, Double height, or as you set it. There is not any way I know to embed a toolbar (which I use) in the taskbar. A pointer (up arrow) to the Toolbar can easily reside in the taskbar.

Comment: Um, embedding a toolbar in the taskbar is trivial.  Right-click on the taskbar, and use the "Toolbars" flyout menuitem.

Comment: Yes, that is pretty much as I posted in my amended answer.. Maybe we are just using different words for the same thing.

Comment: Perhaps! The taskbar is the entire row that, by default, is positioned along the bottom edge of the display.  Within the taskbar, there are 4 possible items: the system tray, the list of open applications, shortcuts, and toolbars (which in turn, can contain more shortcuts).  I'm referring to the last category of items.

Comment: A toolbar (Double UP arrow) can be added to the Task Bar (right click on the Task Bar and select Toolbars you want, including new ones) .  That works the same way as in Windows 7.

Comment: Helpful list of applications in your screenshot! :)  To add a popup menu in the taskbar, I typically create a toolbar with only one item (a folder) and then shrink the toolbar to  to be very small.  Is there a different technique that works well?

Comment: If that question warrants a separate Superuser question, I can write one.

Comment: I use Windows and Toolbars as designed. I do know use a one item toolbar as that does not make sense to me.

Comment: Hmmm... what technique did you use to make the popup menu in your screenshot?

Comment: Snip 'n Sketch (Snagit did not work well).  Open the toolbar, WinKey Shift S and then outline the toolbar and Snip 'n Sketch will copy that to the clipboard.

Comment: LOL :)  I meant what technique did you use to make it exist in Windows, not how did you make the screenshot! :) :) :)

Comment: For the toolbar itself, right click on the Taskbar, select New Toolbar and I used:   
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs and save it.

Comment: Right.  And then you need to shrink the size of that toolbar so each folder within that toolbar doesn't appear horizontally.

Comment: There is no way to do that so far as I know. That is different from how Windows works.

Comment: Unlock the taskbar, and drag the little vertical bar to the left of the word "Programs".  You'll see all the folders.  They are there, but you've already shrunk the toolbar to hide them.

Comment: You can do that, but that puts an enormous number of icons in the Taskbar (more than even double height can hold) so I disable this. Personal preference.  Also be careful with this. Once you do it, you may need to remake the toolbar to get back to default. But It does work after a fashion.